# Where should assert() be used in C resp. C++?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, assert

What are the places we should use the `assert()` function specifically? If it's a situation like determining if an integer value is greater than zero or a pointer is null, we can simply use a private function to check this. In this kind of situation, where should we use `assert()` over a custom written check?

Comment: Uhh... you use assert whenever you want to display a run-time error when the specified condition evaluates to false. This is completely orthogonal to using a custom written check. You still have to write the logic for the check performed by the assert macro.

Comment: the one word I hate is **c/c++** . Is it **C** or **C++** ???

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: is there a difference between usage of it between c and c++?

Comment: @Izza no, but people might answer differently depending on whether you use **C** or **C++**.

Comment: A slight addendum to the comment by @CodyGray; Using `assert` not only displays an error message, but also aborts the execution. If using MSVC++, debug builds will display a dialog with alternatives to ignore, abort or debug. On other systems the `assert` function will call the `abort` function on assertion failure, which causes the `SIGABRT` signal, which normally quits the program with a core dump.

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language. Of course there's a difference. It's like saying red/purple.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: no problems there, I want just the concept behind it, not langauge specific stuff.

Comment: I don't like `C/C++` either. It is undefined behaviour, because `/` is not a sequence point.

Comment: @Izza: Yes. In C++ applications there are alternatives to assert() depending on the type of failure. It is still useful but only for catastrophic failures (where any further execution is likely to execute invalid code). Normal failures can also `potentially (depending on situation)` be handled by exceptions (which usually termination but in a controlled manor releasing resources correctly).

Comment: @LokiAstari Example: Let C=1. The result of C++ is 1, but C itself is 2 after that. So does it divide 2 by 1, or 1 by 1?

Comment: @MrLister: :-) It does not matter. You don't use the result. So it is basically an empty expression the only side affect of which is to increase C. The result of the division is thrown away (and thus for fundamental types will be optimized out of the code). There is only `undefined behavior` if C is modified twice in the same expression (here it is only modified once). That's why I said `C=C/C++` is undefined, but `C/C++` is well defined (You may not know the result by it does not matter as you don't use C/C++ (Well I don't use the language C/C++ I only use C++)).

Comment: Ah... that's what you meant. I though you specifically meant to assign the result to the same variable, while the problem also arises if you assign the result to a different variable. Anyway, it's still called undefined behaviour even if you don't assign the result at all!

Comment: @MrLister: Nop. Its called implementation defined behavior. The difference is `implementation defined` is not dangerous while undefined behavior is dangerous. It only becomes undefined with assignment to self.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

*Context: I write server software for a living, the kind that stays up for weeks before the next version is loaded. So my answers may be biaised toward highly defensive code.*

**The principle.**

Before we delve into the specifics of where to use `assert`, it's important to understand the principle behind it.

`assert` is an essential tool in *Defensive Programming*. It helps validating assumptions (assert them actually) and thus catch *programming* errors (to be distinguished from user errors). The goal of `assert` is to detect erroneous situations, from which recovery is generally not immediately possible.

Example:

```
char const* strstr(char const* haystack, char const* needle) {
  assert(haystack); assert(needle);

  // ...
}
```

**Alternatives.**

In C ? There is little alternative. Unless your function has been designed to be able to pass an error code or return a sentinel value, and this is duly documented.

In C++, exceptions are a perfectly acceptable alternative. However, an `assert` can help produce a memory dump so that you can see exactly what state the program is in at the moment the erroneous situation is detected (which helps debugging), while an exception will unwind the stack and thus lose the context (oups...).

Also, an exception might (unfortunately) get caught by a high level handler (or an unsavory catch from a fellow developer (*you* would not do that, of course)), in which case you could miss completely the error until it's too late.

**Where NOT to use it.**

First, it should be understood that `assert` is only ever useful in *Debug* code. In Release, *NDEBUG* is defined and no code is generated. As a corollary, **in Release `assert` has the same worth as a comment.**

- Never use it for checks that are necessary to the good behavior of the software. Error conditions should be checked and dealt with. Always.

Second, it should be understood that malformed input is part of your life. Would you want your compiler display an `assert` message each time you make an error ? Hum! Therefore:

- Never use it for input data validation. Input data should be validated and errors appropriately reported to the user. Always.

Third, it should be understood that crashes are *not* appreciated. It is expected of your program that it will run smoothly. Therefore, one should not get tempted to leave asserts on in Release mode: Release code ends up in the end user hands and should never crash, ever. At worst, it should shutdown while displaying an error message. It is *expected* that no user data is lost during this process, and even better if upon restarting the user is taken back to where she was: that is what modern browsers do, for example.

- Never leave asserts on in Release.

*Note: for server code, upon "hitting" an assertion, we manage to get back in position for treating the next query in most cases.*

**Where to use it.**

`assert` is on in Debug mode, and so should be used for Debugging. Whenever you test new code, whenever your test suite run, whenever software is in *your* (or your teammates) hands, whenever software is in you QA department hands. Asserts let you spot errors and gives you the full context of the error so that you can *repair*.

- Use it during the development and testing cycles.

Even better. Since you know code will not be executed in Release you can afford to perform *expensive* checks.

*Note: you should also test the Release binary, if only to check the performance.*

**And in Release ?**

Well, in the codebase I work on, we replace the *inexpensive* asserts (the others are ignored) by specific exceptions that are only caught by a high level handler that will log the issue (with backtrace), return a pre-encoded error response and resume the service. The development team is notified automatically.

In software that is deployed, the best practices I have seen imply to create a memory dump and stream it back to the developers for analysis *while* attempting not to lose any user data and behave as courteously as possible toward the unfortunate user. I feel really blessed to be working server-side when I contemplate the difficulty of this task ;)

Comment: +1. great answer relating to the development life cycle as well.

Comment: Exceptions are **not** an alternative to assertions. See my answer.

Comment: @spraff: I kindly disagree. They are an alternative, though they obviously not equivalent. While I prefer working with `assert` during the development and early test phase, I cannot leave them in the software that is used in production, and there they can be replaced with exceptions. There are very few (but severe) cases where you want an `abort` to be called on a production server, exceptions cope with the rest in a more graceful manner.

Comment: If an exception is the right response in production, then it is the right response in development. You can add an *extra* assert to make it fail hard, but the right way to approach it is "if this assert ever fails, then anything that happens after it is as good as UB".

Comment: @spraff: Ah! I don't have this issue --> I use a single (reviewed) assert macro and it either asserts or throws depending on whether it is a Debug or Release build. So as far as I am concerned there is nothing *extra*, it's one or the other depending on circumstances. (Note: except for, as I said, truly expensive checks which are only ever checked in Debug mode. They have their own macro.)

Answer (score 8):

I'm gonna throw out my view of `assert()`. I can find what `assert()` does elsewhere, but stackoverflow provides a good forum for suggestions on how and when to use it.

Both `assert` and `static_assert` serve similar functions. Let's say you have some function `foo`. For example, lets say you have a function `foo(void*)` that assumes its argument is not null:

```
void foo(void* p) {
  assert(p);
  ...
}
```

Your function has a couple people that care about it.

First, the developer who calls your function. He might just look at your documentation and maybe he will miss the part about not allowing a null pointer as the argument. He may not ever **read** the code for the function, but when he runs it in debug mode the assert may catch his inappropriate usage of your function (especially if his test cases are good).

Second (and more important), is the developer who reads your code. To him, your assert says that **after this line, p is not null**. This is something that is sometimes overlooked, but I believe is the most useful feature of the `assert` macro. It documents **and enforces** conditions.

You should use `assert`s to encode this information whenever it is practical. I like to think of it as saying *"at this point in the code, this is true"* (and it says this in a way **so** much stronger than a comment would). Of course, if such a statement doesn't actually convey much/any information then it isn't needed.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's a simple and powerful point to be made:

`assert ()` is for checking *internal* consistency.

Use it to check preconditions, postconditions, and invariants.

When there may be inconsistency due to *external* factors, circumstances which the code can't control locally, then throw an exception. **Exceptions are for when postconditions cannot be satisfied given the preconditions.** Good examples:

- `new int` is ok up to its preconditions, so if memory is unavailable, throwing is the **only** reasonable response. (The postcondition of `malloc` is "a valid pointer *or NULL*")
- The postcondition of a constructor is the existence of an object whose invariants are established. If it can't construct a valid state, throwing is the **only** reasonable response.

`assert` should not be used for the above. By contrast,

```
void sort (int * begin, int * end) {
    // assert (begin <= end); // OPTIONAL precondition, possibly want to throw
    for (int * i = begin, i < end; ++i) {
        assert (is_sorted (begin, i)); // invariant
        // insert *i into sorted position ...
    }
}
```

Checking `is_sorted` is checking that the algorithm is behaving correctly *given its preconditions*. An exception is not a reasonable response.

To cut a long story short: `assert` is for things which WILL NEVER happen IF the program is LOCALLY correct, exceptions are for things which can go wrong even when the code is correct.

Whether or not invalid inputs trigger exceptions or not is a matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

You usually use it when you want the program to abort and display a runtime error if a boolean condition is not true. It is usually used like this:

```
void my_func( char* str )
{
   assert ( str != NULL );
   /* code */
}
```

It can also be used with functions that return a NULL pointer on failure:

```
SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 16, SDL_HWSURFACE );
assert ( screen != NULL );
```

The exact error message `assert()` gives, depends on you compiler but it usually goes along these lines:

```
Assertion failed: str, mysrc.c, line 5
```